# Merging Multiple Word Documents with OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am merging the documents with the following code. The simple documents that contain text are merging just fine and my RichEditControl can load the final doc and display it. However, some other document with fancy graphics are not loading. I am getting exceptions when I call LoadDocument. Any idea what can do to remedy this problem?

```
    public void MergeWordDocuments()//string filePathSrc1, string filePathSrc2)
    {
        using (Log.VerboseCall())
        {
            if (SelectedChaptersList == null ||  SelectedChaptersList.Count == 0)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show("No Chapter Documents Selected", Properties.Settings.Default.AppTitle,
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }

            SelectedChaptersList.Sort((x, y) => x.ChapterNum.CompareTo(y.ChapterNum));

            string manualFilePath = Path.Combine(mManualOutputDir, "tempManualFileName.docx");
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(manualFilePath))
                {
                        File.Delete(manualFilePath);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Verbose(ex);
            }

            string firstFilePath = Path.Combine(mManualOutputDir, Path.Combine(SelectedChaptersList[0].FilePath,
                                                                  SelectedChaptersList[0].FileName +
                                                                  SelectedChaptersList[0].FileType));
            File.Copy(firstFilePath, manualFilePath);

            using (WordprocessingDocument destinationDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(manualFilePath, true))
            {
                // This is mainPart of the Manual
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = destinationDocument.MainDocumentPart;

                // If the document doesn't have a main document part, add one
                if (mainPart == null)
                {
                    mainPart = destinationDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
                    new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
                }

                MergeDocument(mainPart, manualFilePath);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MergeDocument(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string manualFilePath)
    {
        using (Log.VerboseCall())
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < SelectedChaptersList.Count; i++)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(SelectedChaptersList[i].FilePath,
                                                SelectedChaptersList[i].FileName + SelectedChaptersList[i].FileType);

                // Open the source document from the list to be merged into manual
                using (WordprocessingDocument sourceDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false))
                {
                    // Take care of all the necessary imports/merges of styles, fonts, etc.

                    // Import the body content from the source document
                    foreach (var element in sourceDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements())
                    {
                        mainPart.Document.Body.Append(element.CloneNode(true));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ManualUserCtrl_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Log.VerboseCall())
        {
            if (this.Visible == true)
            {
                string manualFilePath = Path.Combine(mManualOutputDir, "tempManualFileName.docx");
                ManualRichEditCtrl.LoadDocument(manualFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

At the end the LoadDocument throws the following exceptions:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Text.DecoderFallbackException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Text.DecoderFallbackException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in DevExpress.RichEdit.v22.2.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in DevExpress.Office.v22.2.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in DevExpress.RichEdit.v22.2.Core.dll
```

Comment: I think you probably need to deal with the problem of how to keep existing references to other parts and make them work. If so, probably non-trivial to say the least - you could have a look at the DocumentBuilder code by Eric a white, e.g. perhaps start at https://github.com/danbetts/OpenXmlPowerTools2023/blob/main/OpenXmlPowerTools2023/Documents/DocumentBuilder.cs

Comment: Good reference link for the future. For now, I was able to resolve it by switching to Word.Interop, which basically designed for the problems like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be solvable, however, for now, I was able to resolve it by switching to Word.Interop, which is basically designed for the problems like that.